# MonoTouch Master-Detail with multiple items in master controller

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm really green to Mono-Touch, but a seasoned c# developer.  Here's my question.  I would like to create an application that uses a master/detail paradigm.  The detail with have a tab controller so I can change the context of the master view.  However, for each master I may want to choose a date, a category, and an order to bring up the details (on the detail view).  Can anyone help with a sample project?  It seams like this should be fairly simple to accomplish, but I haven't found anything.  Again, I'd have a calendar view (For Date), a Picker (for Categories active during the date chosen) and a list view (for orders pertaining to the category).